# How adequate would 48-bit floating point be?

Tags: performance, floating-point

Though power of 2 word sizes look in hindsight like a natural consensus, historical computers used quite a wide variety, including but not limited to 9, 18, 36, 12, 24 and 60 bits.

Power-of-2 computers have tended to end up (leaving aside 8087's 80-bit extended precision) with a choice between 32 and 64-bit floating point formats.

A 12/24 bit computer, when implementing floating point, would naturally tend to 48 bits. Indeed, this precision was actually used in some cases even on power-of-2 computers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928449/what-type-is-this-6-byte-48-bit-number-floating-point-integer

Would 48 bits be enough for most scientific and engineering applications (in a way that 32 is not), or would such a computer need to incur the cost of supporting a higher precision such as 96 bits?

Comment: For a float of a given width we can say both "It's enough" and "it's not enough". But 48 bit floats were common IIRC on Galaksija, C64, Apple II etc etc. so you may need to say more specifically what you're expecting of your float.

Comment: @Wilson For serious science and engineering work, of the kind that was done on mainframes and supercomputers and ultimately PCs with floating point hardware, finite element modeling, simulating fluid dynamics and protein folding, that kind of thing.

Comment: You still haven't said what is 'serious' work.  All the examples you give in your comment would be performed at whatever precision was relevant to the particular task.

Comment: The Roman numeral system didn't even know floating point. The Romans, however, tended to ignore that and did very "serious design and engineering work" with it.

Comment: @Chenmunka Okay, to be specific: Calculating the weather forecast for Western Europe. Modelling the fluid flow over an airplane wing. Calculating the folding of protein molecules.

Comment: Again.  Each of those would be done to whichever precision was appropriate for the task.  On one day you may use low precision, on another high precision.

Comment: This is both untrue and annoyingly obstructive. We can in fact say more about precision requirements than the empty tautology 'whatever precision is appropriate for the task'. In particular, to a first approximation, decades of experience have shown that 64-bit floating point is usually adequate whereas 32 bits very often is not. (The major exceptions being graphics rendering and neural networks.)

Comment: We can indeed say more.  In my experience, occasionally, 64-bit FP is inadequate and you use arbitrary precision.  Other times, you use integer arithmetic and scale everything.  Is 48-bit adequate?  Yes and no, it depends.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to double the size: For machines with word size 8/12/24, there are more possibilities after after 48 bits than doubling to 96 bits (e.g. 56 bits for 8 bit words, 72 bits for 24 bit words, ...). You could even implement variable mantissa and exponent sizes in your library (because all this will be software, anyway)...

Comment: Turbo Pascal used a 48-bit floating-point type [1+15+32], and IMHO that would be the "right" type to use for most applications on processors without an FPU.  On many such processors, computations with such types would be slightly more efficient than with IEEE single, and much more efficient than IEEE double.  Too bad C doesn't allow implementations to define "double" in such fashion [it requires just a smidgen more precision than can be supported efficiently without an FPU].

Comment: @dirkt: The best way to perform a sequence of operations on floating-point values of a given type is often to promote them to a slightly larger type, do the operations, and round the result back to the original precision *at predictable times*.  IEEE-754 recognized this with its extended-precision type, but unfortunately C89 botched the semantics of "long double", causing IEEE-754's extended-precision math to get an unfairly bad reputation.

Comment: An old Nicolet FTIR spectrometer I used decades ago used a 24-bit word computer, making a 48-bit floating point variable just right...

Comment: @supercat: Um, yes, but what is your point? You can do all of this flexibly if it's a software library anyway. And the "slightly larger" type is NOT necessarily a type with double the size, just having one more word is usually enough to avoid the worst rounding problems. My point still stands: It's NOT necessary to double the size (unless you are bound by hardware implementations where this is the only option).

Comment: @dirkt: I should have started with something like "indeed", to indicate that I was agreeing with your point, and noting that a "less than twice as big" type was a good feature that was included in IEEE-754, but has fallen by the wayside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just making a rough estimation, using:

- 1 bit for the sign,
- 8 bit for the exponent (range 10^-127 to 10^128)

would leave 39 bits for the mantissa. You need about 10 bits for 3 digits (2^10 is 1024), so you would have 12 digits precision in a range of 1x10<sup>-127</sup> to 1x10<sup>128</sup>.

Seems enough for most things, I can imagine.

Comment: A more useful 48-bit type would be sign+exp15+mant32, using an explicit leading "1".  On many FPU-less platforms, operations with a 32-bit mantissa which is stored in a word by itself will be much more efficient than operations on anything bigger.

Comment: Incidentally, Turbo Pascal used a 48-bit floating-point type, and if C had included a `long float` type to which `float` values promote, and which whose precision could be anything between `float` and `long double`, implementations without FPUs could have processed such a type more efficiently than a 32-bit `float`.